# Java2MySQL > Communication link failure due to underlying exception again

Tags: java, mysql, connection

I'm making program in Java, which connects to MySQL database. As first class was class with single static method returning `java.sql.Connection`. After it was debugged and connection was working I never touch it again. And few days ago I discovered my program was returning this error:

> **com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: 
> Communications link failure
>   due to underlying exception
>
> BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION
>
>   com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException
>
>  MESSAGE:
>  Communication link
>   failure due to underlying exception:
>
> BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION
>
>   java.io.EOFException MESSAGE: Can not read response from server.
>   Expected 4 bytes, read 0 before connection was unexpectedly lost.**
>
> **STACKTRACE:**
>
> **...**

- I installed MySQL Server v. 5.1.62
- I'm using MySQL/J connector v. 5.0.8 (downloaded from mysql.com)
- also I put in classpath in NetBeans sqljdbc4.jar

Thing I can't understand is fact I didn't change user name and password on my localhost since I created my database. Only thing I changed are: add more tables and changed columns in tables, but that would not trigger this error. And thing I did with my project is I changed charset from UTF-8 to UTF-16, but I guess it hardly can affect my connection method.

If I change connector and put in classpath  connector v. 5.1.22 it returns error:
**Access denied for user "root@localhost" (using password: YES)**
even I declared all privileges for user root.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend following:

> 1. Firstly confirm if network is fine between two servers:    a. ping from your server to your database server.    b. use MTR unix tool to
>      ensure connectivity between two servers.
> 2. Are you using connection pool ? If yes, then try to restart the server. Probably few of the connections in your connection pool are in
>      closed state.

Lets firstly resolve the first issue.  Other issue Access denied for user "root@localhost" (using password: YES) is an independent issue which we can discuss later.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot tell I'm using Win 7 machine. Thank you for reply. I setup even more connections in my pool and it didn't work (I have about 10 connections to database, when application starts and pool accepts 15).
**BUT!!**
I didn't forget I changed my project's encoding from UTF-8 (I had since beginning) to Unicode (because I wanted use East European alphabet in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();` windows, since its my native alphabet). Just for test I changed charset back to UTF-8 and my connection is working again. Honestly... I don't understand this.